# How to increment in php without doing a for loop

Tags: php, curl

Im doing a multi curl in PHP using this code:

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();


// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
```

As you can see in the code Im adding two handles using `curl_multi_add_handle` to `$mh` 
Is there anyway to add the handles $ch1 and $ch2 without repeating the code? 
Usually I would do a for loop i++ but that is not an option here. 
So Im looking for something like this:

```
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,[$ch1,$ch2]); ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop, but use an array instead of a set of variables which have the same name except for a number on the end.

Comment: You mean something like this: `for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch[$x]);
}` It doesn't work

Comment: I tried a different version which also doesn't work: `$ar = array('$ch1','$ch2');
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($ar); $x++) {
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ar[$x]);
}` Feel free to elaborate

Comment: You're passing it strings instead of handles! http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/ has a fuller example.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much, and thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

As per @Quentin answer, You can do it like below:

```
$urls = array('http://www.example.com/', 'http://www.example1.com/', 'http://www.example2.com/');
$url_count = count($urls);

$curl_arr = array();
$mh = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $url_count; $i++)
{
    $url = $urls[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl_arr[$i]);
}
$active = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time